# How to use atomic header c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, redhat, atomic

Im trying to compile a c++ file that includes atomic headr,

I am getting this error:

```
#error <atomic> is not supported on this single threaded system
```

Im using cross compiled clang.
Im running on redHat 6.9

Comment: So your host system is RedHat 6.9, but what is your *target* system? And as the error message says, it seems to not support threads which makes atomics kind of useless.

Comment: The message seems clear: apparently, you target some kind of embedded system that doesn't support threads and so has no use for atomics. What more do you wish to know?

Comment: Did you add `-pthread` to the compiler flags?

Comment: That said, a little strange not to support `<atomic>` as a bunch of equivalent non-atomic operations. Just makes it harder to write portable code.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious that you are compiling the code for a system that Clang thinks does not support multi-threading, so there is no need for atomic operations.

Answer (score 5):

This error means that [libcxx](https://libcxx.llvm.org/) for the target system was configured without threading support. The documentation for `libcxx` [outlines its threading support](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/ThreadingSupportAPI.html).

> **_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_THREADS**
>
> This macro is defined when libc++ is built without threading support. It should not be manually defined by the user.

The error you're getting means that `_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_THREADS` is defined. Specifically, from the [`atomic`](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/atomic) header:

```
#ifdef _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_THREADS
#error <atomic> is not supported on this single threaded system
#endif
```

You will need to find out if you can build/configure libcxx for your target platform with threading support as outlined in the libcxx documentation.

Comment: Why "no threading support" means "`<atomic>` is not supported"?